# cython import in extension types

Tags: python, cython, python-import

Is it possible to import other modules in a cython extension types? I tried and got an error that I do not understand and could not fix after some web search.

See this minimal example:

```
.
├── a.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── main.py
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── a.pyx
    ├── __init__.py
```

I run `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` in the `src` folder to start the build process.

The `__init__.py` module is empty.

**a.pyx**:

```
import sys # This import is the problem, doesn't matter what I import

cdef class A:

    cdef int my

    def __init__(self):
        self.my = 2

    def foo(self):
        print(str(self.my))
```

**setup.py**:

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import find_packages, Extension, setup


setup(
    name='cy_pack',
    ext_modules=cythonize([Extension("a", ["src/a.pyx"])]),
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

**main.py**:

```
import a

ob = a.A()    
ob.foo()
```

When I try to run `main.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simon/Documents/cythonTest/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import a
  File "src/a.pyx", line 2, in init src.a (src/a.c:983)
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

The thing is, if I delete the import line in `a.pyx` no error will occur and the expected output is generated.